# WPF can't populate treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm new to WPF and trying to wrap my head around the preferred way to handle data.  I found this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) that explains the databinding for a tree view. I have tried to create my code in a similar way, but I can't see why that code runs fine and mine doesn't.

Anyway, I've defined some class for artists/albums/songs

```
class LibArtist
{
    public string Name { get { return mName; } }
    string mName;
    public ObservableCollection<LibAlbum> Albums;

    public LibArtist(string name)
    {
        mName = name;
        Albums = new ObservableCollection<LibAlbum>();
    }


}

class LibAlbum
{
    public string Name { get { return mName; } }
    public string Artist { get { return mArtist.Name; } }
    public uint Year { get { return mYear; } }
    public ObservableCollection<LibSong> mSongs = new ObservableCollection<LibSong>();
    uint mYear;
    LibArtist mArtist;
    string mName;

    public LibAlbum(string pName, LibArtist pArtist, uint pYear)
    {
        mName = pName;
        mArtist = pArtist;
        mYear = pYear;
    }
}
class LibSong
{
    public string Title { get { return mName; } }
    public string Artist { get { return mArtist; } }
    public string Album { get { return mAlbum; } }
    public string Location { get { return mLocation; } }
    public uint Year { get { return mYear; } }
    string mName;
    uint mYear;
    string mAlbum;
    string mArtist;
    string mLocation;
    public LibSong(string pSongLocation)
    {
        mLocation = pSongLocation;
        TagLib.File lFile = TagLib.File.Create(pSongLocation);
        mAlbum = lFile.Tag.Album;
        mName = lFile.Tag.Title;
        mArtist = lFile.Tag.AlbumArtists.Length > 0 ? lFile.Tag.AlbumArtists[0] : "???";
        //use tag lib to fill the data if this file exists
        mYear = lFile.Tag.Year;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        LibSong temp = obj as LibSong;
        if (temp == null)
            return false;
        if (temp.Location == this.Location)
            return true;
        if (temp.Artist == this.Artist && temp.Album == this.Album && temp.Year == this.Year)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And these sit in a library class:

```
class Library
{
    public SortedDictionary<string, List<string>> mArtistsToAlbums;
    SortedDictionary<string, List<LibSong>> mAlbumsToSongs;
    public List<LibSong> mSongList;
    public ObservableCollection<LibSong> mSongList2;
    public ObservableCollection<LibAlbum> mAlbumList;

    public ObservableCollection<LibArtist> mArtistList;
    ...
}
```

In my main window, I set the data context of my treeview to the library object:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        mPlayer = new izPlayer(0);


        InitializeComponent();

        libraryTreeView.DataContext = mLibrary;
        mLibrary = new Library();
        mLibrary.CreateTestData();
```

In my xaml, I define the treeview like so:

```
<TreeView Name="libraryTreeView"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        ItemsSource="{Binding mArtistList}"
        Height="443" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="344" MouseDoubleClick="libraryTreeView_MouseDoubleClick" 
         >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>      
    </TreeView>
```

And when I run this, I don't get anything displayed in the treeview.  As I said, I'm not sure why this is different from the example code, or why it isn't displaying the data inside mArtistList.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for the `TreeView` Dennis' answer is a great resource. If you're not getting any items even in at the top level thought, it may be due to invalid binding sources. It looks like `Library` is declaring public fields

```cs
public ObservableCollection<LibArtist> mArtistList;
```

In order to use binding in the XAML these sources need to be public properties

```cs
public ObservableCollection<LibArtist> mArtistList { get; set; }
```

Comment: That did the trick, though I also started getting an error that Items has to be empty for itemSource to be used even though I'm not settings items. Clear() did the trick though and everything seems to be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally different from example code (I mean XAML difference).

The main concept for the data-bound `TreeView` in WPF is that you must describe [hierarchical data templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your nodes, because you want to display hierarchical data.

Your XAML should look like this:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourNamespace:LibArtist}" ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}">
    <!-- the template tree for displaying artist's data -->
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourNamespace:LibAlbum}" ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}">
    <!-- the template tree for displaying song's data -->
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- and so on -->
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. After I started messing around with the file to try and figure out what was wrong I tried seeing if just a non hierarchy list would show up.